# NativeScript: Formatting number typescript

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I am totally new to nativescript and googling for the some basic stuff is harder than it should be...
What i want to do is basically this: 
I have the number

1234567.89

in a variable, and i want to show it in a label with the format

"1,234,567.89"

Also, always show 2 decimals in case that 89 is 0 instead.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Just to add on to the answers below, this isn't a NativeScript question but a general javascript question (which includes typescript since it's a superset of js)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you target to modern browsers you can use:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-us', {minimumFractionDigits: 2}).format(1234567.89)
```

or

```
(1234567.89).toLocaleString('en-us', {minimumFractionDigits: 2})
```

For browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Comment: thanks, both suggestions and the link were what is was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript meaning that what you can do in JavaScript can be done in TS as well (but not the other way around). That said look [at this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_numbers.htm).

Now talking in the context of NativeScript, you can either provide the data to your binding context in the right format or use [valueConverter](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/_ui_core_bindable_.valueconverter.html).

[Here](https://github.com/dmccuskey/nativescript-docs/blob/master/bindings.md) you can find examples on how to use value converters with data binding