# How to parse a number specifying pattern, decimal separator and grouping separator in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, parsing, internationalization, numbers

I will immediately admit that I'm a java developer and are searching for a function similar to [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), something like:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols unusualSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
unusualSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('|');
unusualSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('^');
DecimalFormat weirdFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.###", unusualSymbols);
Number myNum = weirdFormatter.parse("8^453|13");
```

<sup>Code adapted from [Oracle javase i18n](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)</sup>

Every resource I can find related to this is either just to format (not parsing)

[How to specify thousand separator for number pipe in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672225/how-to-specify-thousand-separator-for-number-pipe-in-angular-4)

[NativeScript: Formatting number typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325730/nativescript-formatting-number-typescript)

or people using regex to substitute (that seems crazy to me)

[How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/how-can-i-parse-a-string-with-a-comma-thousand-separator-to-a-number)

or some general topics that does not consider interationalization

[TypeScript Converting a String to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667713/typescript-converting-a-string-to-a-number)

[In Typescript, How to check if a string is Numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437476/in-typescript-how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric)

I did some digging on angular's GitHub and I did find this class [format_number](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/i18n/format_number.ts) but also this seems only related to formatting not parsing or at least I can not figure out how to use it.

---

The question is: Is there an object like this in Angular?, if not also this is a valid answer (I can stop searching). If you like to pass a solution using an external library please remember to [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do:

```
var numberStr = "8^453|13";
var number = parseFloat(numberStr.replace("^", "").replace("|", "."));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yes I know how to do my simple example with regex (and I probably can figure out a more complex for all my cases) but to be honest my question is if angular have this class or not. The reason I'm looking for a non regex answer is that I would be surprised if there is not [better tools to do the job](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/113243/227993)